# overflow menu on ios similar to android

Tags: ios, overflow

Please can someone help me on how we can do an overflow menu similar to android (Action Bar).

I tried to do a UIView and hide or show on click but if we have a native way, it would be better.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first store your options which you want to show in menu in an array. After that render that array in table view and then use that tableview on click of that button. By this way you can get an overflow menu. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Your welcome, if you find this helpful I would ask you to please accept my answer with that correct mark & a vote up